# My Android app that runs in the background, is the functionality I need possible?

Tags: android

Here is what I am looking to do, is this possible with an Android application?

A user installs my application. My application then runs in the background, it has no UI, and it constantly checks if certain other applications have been started. If they have it will take screenshots every few seconds and save them in a specific folder.

- Can this be done, **can my (background) application determine when other applications are running?**

My application will use OCR on the screenshots and if I detect certain text strings I want to show a input box on the screen and ask the user to enter a comment in the the box and then click submit.

- Can this be done, **can my application that is running in the background, overlay an input form on top of some other application that is currently running**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both are possible.

The first one is only possible by continuously looking which app is in foreground, so it's extremely expensive in battery...

Comment: An example of the first question is visible with this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock

This app shows a login page if a specific app is started.